# Is there a way to increase the contrast for blockquotes, such as the old style with a light-yellow background?

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown-rendering

I noticed a recent change in the markdown rendering of blockquotes on stackoverflow.com: they now display as regular text, with just a thin grey vertical bar the the left.

This change seems to be a design decision, as a remedy to some issues that seem largely irrelevant to Stack Overflow itself but may affect other Stack Exchange sites. The downside is it makes blockquotes much less visible in questions and answers where it has been used for a decade to quote parts of the question of fragments from relevant documentation (such as the C Standard) precisely with the intent to make these quotations stand out clearly. The new style changes the look of tens of thousands of answers in a way that may offend their authors.

This change was proposed in [Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes) and put in production, despite a majority of upvoted answers that voiced opposition or underlined irrelevance.

Is there a way to obtain more contrast between quoted blocks and the rest of the text in the post?

Comment: @Makyen: sadly it does. But it raises more questions: why was this decision made?

Comment: For that, you're going to need to delve into [Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919). Personally, I just added an additional style, `blockquote { background-color: #fbf2d4; color: #0d0e0f; }` to the personal adjustments I make to SE pages. [Note: you don't need the `color`, but I like a bit more contrast than exists with the default text color on the old `background-color`.] Sure, I think it should be changed for everyone, but SE takes only limited input wrt. design decisions.

Comment: @Makyen: how to you use this style?

Comment: Personally, I added it to the chunk of CSS styles which are added to SE pages by the userscript which I use for personal adjustments, but that userscript also does quite a few things in addition to adding a block of CSS. For adding userscripts, I primarily use the Tampermokey browser extension, although Violentmonkey is a reasonable open source alternative. There are *lots* of userscripts available which enhance Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow pages. You can find some on [stackapps.se]. However, I'm not aware of a userscript which addresses this specific blockquote change.

Comment: If using a userscript, the JavaScript to insert the style into the DOM could be: `document.documentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<style type="text/css">blockquote { background-color: #fbf2d4; color: #0d0e0f; }</style>')`.

Comment: For just adding some CSS, there are a number of browser extensions which allow you to add custom CSS to specified pages/domains. For that, I'd [recommend **against** "Stylish", for privacy reasons](//security.stackexchange.com/q/199218) (read the pages linked from the question and answer there if you want more detail about why there are privacy issues with that extension). However, I really haven't used a browser extension which is intended just for adding/changing CSS, so I can't really recommend one (also, which one to use will depend on your browser).

Comment: @Makyen: I already use a custom script to solve some aggravating key binding issues. I shall try and add the style patch to it, but I resent the fact that this change hurts readability for casual readers, reducing visual contrast intended by the posters.

Comment: I don't mind reopening this question (on MSO) if it is completely edited. Currently it is mostly still "was this a deliberate change", and that is a duplicate.

Comment: @halfer: I edited the question, and added more constructive points

Comment: OK, voted to reopen.

Comment: Personally I think this change is excellent. People have been _way_ abusing the "it stands out" by using quote formatting for announcements/headings/notices. **That's not what quote formatting is for.** So if you've been relying on it, consider this a lesson well learned: don't rely on specific formatting for your markup, but instead use the appropriate markup for the semantics of your text.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I don't see anyone arguing for the misuse of blockquote format which you've assumed is being discussed. While I agree blockquote formatting, particularly as it was, *could* be misused, the fact that things which are actualy quotes (e.g. quoting specifications, etc) used to more clearly stand out from the page is certainly something that's of legitimate concern. For example, there are many people who feel/felt that it was better to have errors and program output in quote format, because the formatting differentiated them. [Personally, I prefer code formatting for those].

Comment: @Makyen I assume that someone, somewhere, is arguing for the misuse of blockquote format ;) I don't personally see why quotes need to stand out so much from "first class" text, but as I've said to others elsewhere on this topic I do see where you're coming from and am happy to agree to disagree on that part

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: blockquote seemed semantically appropriate to quote from the question and from the Standard, and the increased contrast was welcome for this kind of quote and IMHO quite pleasing and elegant. So I don't really agree on the *misuse* qualification. What matters to me is to have a way to make quotes stand out from regular text. This may seem illegitimate, but  I do not think I am the only one with this concern. The grey sidebar may be appropriate for interactive forums and blogs with nested quoted blocks, but this kind of discussion does not happen on SO.

Comment: @chqrlie Example of misuse [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99845/692649), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/4386278). (I admit they're not the _best_ examples, but it's easier to search for "Moderator note" than to find the better examples produced by question-writers and answer-authors... and I only have a few mins. Also oftentimes people kindly fix those misuses with edits.) Enjoying quotes standing out is one thing, but using the quote formatting for not-quote things _because_ they ~currently~ used to stand out is quite another.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: examples of *misuse* by moderators do not really support your point.

Comment: @chqrlie I don't see why not. And, even if they didn't, read the rest of the comment.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: As commented above, blockquotes were the semantically correct tool and in most cases for SO the increased contrast provided by the light-yellow background was appropriate and quite useful. Hence my question for SO: is there a way to increase the contrast for blockquotes, such as the old style with a light-yellow background?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right. I have bad feelings about that, too. IMHO, It was much easier to read before. I´m sceptical about the reason of misuse as described by user @AsteroidswithWings in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394644/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-contrast-for-blockquotes-such-as-the-old-style-w/394735#comment760008_394644) since users also can misuse blockquotes yet.

---

> Is there a way to obtain more contrast between quoted blocks and the rest of the text in the post?

As side solution and without diving too deep by using f.e. userscripts as suggested by user @Makyen in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394644/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-contrast-for-blockquotes-such-as-the-old-style-w#comment759948_394644) one can for example use two horizontal bars, like:
`_________________`
to make it stand out a little bit clearer:

---

> This is a quote. Unfortunately, It is hard to distinguish to the other text.

---

I also like to change the style of the quote to *italic* and use double quotation marks to emphasize the quote nature. If you want to emphasize a certain text part, you still can make it bold:

---

> *"This is a **quote**. Unfortunately, It is hard to **distinguish** to the other text."*

---

But it would definitely be better, if Stack Overflow would improve the design of the block quotes on their own without the need for a user doing such dragging workarounds. Never mind the uncountable questions and answers which would required to be changed to increase readability.

I do not say that the yellow-background exclusively need to be brought back but I´m certain that the design could be improved (with a distinct and lightly colored or patterned  background for example).

Comment: You can also just use `<hr>` instead of typing out a whole line.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Good hint. But I`m personally faster just to go with writing a bar. I guess it may be similar by others.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you giving suggestions as to how the blockquotes should be implemented or how to emphasize them more using the current tools?

Comment: @Scratte I`m just answering the question "*Is there a way to obtain more contrast between quoted blocks and the rest of the text in the post?*" in my personal way. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I understood that to be more a question to the decision makers than to anyone that could provide ways to use/misuse the current markdown as highlighters. Especially because it seems unfeasible to edit those "tens of thousands of answers".

Comment: @Scratte I understand your concern and be with you. I changed the character of my answer.

Comment: @exnihilo: both backtick text markup and indented blocks can be used within blockquotes and I use those extensively when quoting the C Standard in my answers. These answers now look much less explicit (example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59902759/4593267 ). I would like SO to revert the rendering changes, possibly on a site by site basis, decided by contributor consensus, or at the very least to add more control to contributors and make extra markup available to achieve increased contrast (such as `>!!` for example, although this would require hacking previous contributions, which is a pain).