# Is there a way to increase the contrast for the 'deleted post' background?

Tags: bug, design, accessibility

Whilst some of the recent changes to the styling of Stack Overflow are [extremely noticeable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394644/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-contrast-for-blockquotes-such-as-the-old-style-w), one thing that *appears* to have changed for the worse is the 'deleted' background.

Deleted posts have a subtle pink background, but they also have both context from a *deleted* or *hidden* message, and a much larger area of colour. As such, they don't cause a particular issue (at least to my eyes).

[image]

In the Flag Summary, however, there is nothing but a thin, faintly-coloured background to convey the information that a post has been deleted. This is an accessibility issue, as the use of weakly contrasting colours to convey information is, in my case at least, almost completely lost.

[image]

This background colour (#fdf3f4), has a [contrast ratio](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=FDF3F4&bcolor=FFFFFF) with the white of 1.08:1 which, similar to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328289/504460) is insufficient.

Can the contrast be reviewed, particularly in deference to those of us with colour vision deficiencies?

Comment: It's not critical information; it's only supplemental information that the flagged post has been deleted. You could easily see this by clicking the link. I don't want to make the text any more difficult to read, or add anything more distracting to the page. I use this a lot, and that would be very annoying to me.

Comment: It seems unlikely, to me, that the goal of asking for better contrast for accessibilty would be met by changes that make the text more difficult to read. I agree that I wouldn't like to see anything added to the page; I was merely saying that as there is nothing else to give context, that the contrast doesn't work for everyone.

Comment: So, what is the proposal? Darken the background color? It seems that would interfere with the text contrast.

Comment: As a colour-impaired person, I wouldn't wish to suggest what shades of what colours would work best in general, but I can say that on this screen alone, there are: tags, my name badge, the new contributor badge, the 'This post is hidden' message, and the Featured on Meta sections, all clearly visible to me, all with clearly readable text.

Comment: There's no great solution here based on color alone. I think we'd have to solve this with a larger re-design that doesn't use color as the sole distinguisher of a deleted post—this was always a hack solution, and is super inaccessible in _general_.

Comment: Someone could probably create a script to add the word "Deleted" to the beginning or end of the div tag with the `bg-red-050` class.

Comment: Related: [New red background for deleted posts is too light and not visible on high-contrast screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344873/289905).

Comment: @AaronShekey The deleted post has a thin deeper red line just above the fainted pink. The flag summary does not have such a line. Couldn't such an added line be a solution?

Comment: Adding more visual noise, like "Deleted" or an icon, is precisely what I had in mind when I said, "I don't want to...add anything more distracting to the page."

Comment: @CodyGray Sometimes unimpaired people have to make small concessions to allow impaired people to have the same level of user experience as we do. I don't think a small line or icon or text will distract that much. We could also simply make the title of deleted posts italic or something... Or would that cause you to drop your coffee and stare at the screen for hours? :-)

Comment: @CodyGray If they want the site to be accessible, it shouldn’t [rely solely on color to convey meaning](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-without-color.html) anyway (at least by WCAG standard). But when I said “a script” I meant a userscript OP could use in the meantime. Aaron has already said this would require a larger redesign, I wasn’t trying to suggest that shouldn’t happen.

Comment: There's a reason I led my first comment with the statement, "it's not critical information". If this were critical information, then I agree, there needs to be more signals other than color for accessibility reasons. But non-critical information, information that is merely supplemental and whose lack of accessibility does not in any way interfere with one's usage of the site, does not need to be rendered in multiple ways. A single one (color) is sufficient. I wouldn't have objection to adding a border to the background, but I dislike changing to italics or adding icons.